# MVC e alteração dinâmica de idioma

Tags: php, mvc, design-pattern, projeto-de-software

Tenho um `MVC` próprio que implemento nos meus projectos em `PHP`. Este suporta vários idiomas e por defeito obtêm do browser o idioma activo/inicial.

No entanto existem projectos que requerem a funcionalidade de modificar o idioma com um simples clique.

A solução que entendo melhor é pelo URL ou seja:

**url p/idioma automático:** `http://meuprojecto.com/[controller]/[action]`

**url p/forçar idioma/locale:** `http://meuprojecto.com/pt-PT/[controller]/[action]`.

Como se pode observar utilizo a norma LOCALE para obter o idioma... Sendo que implementei utilizando o hífen ou do underscore. Desta forma sempre que a framework detecte este tipo de URL modifica para o projecto o LOCALE inicialmente obtido do browser.

Tendo a minha solução, gostaria de avaliar outras formas de resolver este problema.

A minha pergunta é: que outros mecanismos conhecem dentro de implementações em `PHP` resolvidos de forma diferente? Tenho pensado em inserir suporte para a presença de uma tag `ISO 639-1` para identificar o idioma mas acho que estarei a complicar, ou não?

Comment: Não tem relação com MVC..   Mas independente disso, ISO3166-alpha2 refere-se a códigos de países. Recomendo que utilize os códigos  ISO para idiomas ao invés de países, pois como determinar, por exemplo, o idioma de um país bilíngue?

Comment: @DanielOmine não percebi porque não tem relação com MVC.  Obrigado pela correção do ISO pois enganei-me e já corrigí. Dizer ainda que por idioma parece-me bem mas o LOCALE é de facto mais epecífico pois posso assim identificar pt-PT ou pt-BR, en-GB ou en-US por exemplo. O que para algumas implementações faz toda a diferença.

Comment: @DanielOmine no entanto a minha duvida, em adoptar o ISO é por existem efectivamente implementações mais abrangentes e que não requerem tanta especificidade. e um url http://exemplo.com/pt é bem mais simples do que http://exemplo.com/pt-PT

Comment: ok, imaginei isso. O problema de usar somente o código do idioma é para o caso de países diferentes. O código "pt" é português, porém, o português do Brasil é diferente de Portugual.   Sobre MVC, é indiferente se usa MVC ou não.. por isso não tem relação alguma.

Comment: o locale code é baseado na estrutura [código do idioma]-[código do país] ambos em 2 dígitos..  Porém, há algumas exceções como "az-Cyrl-AZ", por exemplo.

Comment: Como dito acima, isso não possui relação com o uso do MVC. Se eu bem entendi seu problema, você pode utilizar algumas bibliotecas de internacionalização (recomendo a [php-i18n](https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n)).

Comment: sei o que é um MVC e enquadrei a selecção dentro do componente que construí para controlar as saídas no que respeita ao idioma dentro do componente que criei e é por isso que os relacionei. A minha pergunta é simples se conhecem outras formas de definir um idioma além da que implementei. @WilliamUrbano obrigado pela sua sugestão vou investigar.

Comment: @chambelix : Tente armazenar o locale na sua sessão por meio de alguma URL que o usuário irá acessar e esse idioma será definido. Desta forma não haverá necessidade de incluir o locale na sua URL.

Answer (score 2):

O esquema mais elegante que já encontrei para o PHP [está no CakePHP, no módulo `i18n`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html).

Basicamente, define-se o sistema inteiro com funções de internacionalização como esta:

```
__("MinhaString")
```

"MinhaString" é entendida como uma chave de *resource*. Todas as chaves podem ser extraídas [usando um procedimento automático como este](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html).

Depois disso, os arquivos podem ser traduzidos com o auxílio de uma ferramenta como o [Poedit](https://poedit.net/).

Comment: muito obrigado pelo seu tempo...não conhecia e fui ver. Engraçado que utilizam a mesma lógica nas pastas baseadas em Locale. Só que eu não utilizo o POedit utilizo ficheiros com array em php. Mas dá para dar uma análise mais profunda.

Comment: @chambelix Sim, a ideia é só te dar um norte mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você estaria criando um outro meio, que até faria sentido. Mas, ainda assim seria um trabalho extra e para qualquer outra pessoa e pra finalidades de SEO poderia ter efeitos colaterais.

O que posso recomendar seria a implementação de cookies para armazenar e capturar a locale de acordo com o que o usuário queira. Seria mais rápido, você consegue manipular por javascript também, por exemplo, e deixaria o seu código mais legível.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Mas estou com essa implementação em muitos projetos e tem dado resultado e quanto ao SEO não vejo onde pode dar problemas. Quanto à implementação dos cookies foi o que acabei por fazer pois a minha pergunta já tem uns tempos e tive de encontrar uma solução. penso que consegui um bom compromisso que até agora tem resultado. Fugi do javascript. o meu ponto é ver outro tipo de implementações para ver se estou ou não no caminho certo.

Answer (score -3):

Olá, meu caro vejo que é bem antigo o post, mas vou deixar uma outra forma de implementar i18n em um projeto utilizando o padrão MVC, não estou utilizando framework, estrutura pura, divido em pastas, controllers,models,core,views, assim acredito que entenderá bem.
na pasta core, responsável por rodar toda engrenagem, fiz o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei uma pasta de noma langs na raíz do projeto e coloquei os arquivos com os idiomas, são eles: pt-br.ini,en.ini,es.ini

no diretório controllers criei um arquivo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso mesmo ainda na pasta core existe um arquivo controller.php e no construtor adicionei a instância da class Language, ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Certo? Espero que esteja ficando bem claro, enfim, na suas views basta fazer assim:

onde irá acontecer a tradução: lang->get('CONTANT'); ?>//constante criada no arquivo .ini, vou mostrar um pequeno trecho:

//pt-br
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

//en
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

//es
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendeu, assim você consegue traduzir o conteúdo da página com um clique em algum link ou menu ai, espero ter ajudado, valeu