# Sistema multi-linguagem

Tags: php, javascript, html, variáveis-globais

Tenho um website e gostaria de implementar um sistema de multi-language. Tenho algumas duvidas a nível de boas práticas.
Queria ter apenas um domínio `****.com`. Penso que isto me obrigaria a utilizar sistemas implementados em php, ou outras linguagens para comunicar com o servidor, certo?
A minha ideia seria ter uma variável global (não sei se existe algo deste género) e ao carregar na linguagem pretendida isso iria alterar a variável global e sempre que abrisse uma nova pagina do site ele assumiria a nova linguagem.
Seria esta uma boa prática?

Answer (score 1):

Tem alguns recursos que você pode detectar o idioma pelo IP, caso seja a primeira visita do usuário ao seu site. (Esse tipo de serviço pode ser instável, existe outros pagos que são bem mais precisos e confiáveis.)

E armazenar o idioma em um *[Cookie](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.cookies.php)*. Assim toda a vez que o usuário entrar no teu site, você obtém essa informação:

```
$padrao = 'pt-BR';

if (empty($_COOKIE['lang'])){
    // Receba o idioma através de um formulário $_POST['lang']
    // Ou pela URL http://dominio.com/?lang=pt-BR
    // Ou busque um serviço de localização externo e baseie o idioma na localização do usuário

    $lang = $_POST['lang'] || $_GET['lang'] || buscaIdioma();

    $expire = 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 10 anos, ou nunca

    setcookie('lang', $lang, $expire);

    define(LANG, $lang);
} else {
    define(LANG, $_COOKIE['lang']);
}
```

Como definir qual idioma o usuário está usando é o mais simples. A parte mais complicada será fazer a tradução do conteúdo.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

A sua pergunta é relevante e a mesma, para mim, situa-se mais quanto à forma e não quanto ao como.

Eu coloquei uma pergunta que lhe recomendo a leitura:

[MVC e alteração dinâmica de idioma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66557/mvc-e-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-din%C3%A2mica-de-idioma)

Posso falar por experiência que devemos de utilizar uma framework que implemente um MVC para qualquer um dos nossos projectos em PHP. Não irei colocar aqui os motivos pois ultrapassa os escopo da pergunta, mas é certo que alguns já entregam alguma lógica para controlo de idiomas.

Para quem, como eu, que profissionalmente utiliza uma framework própria e que implementa um MVC próprio e por várias razões é forçado a encontrar mecanismos para resolver vários problemas. O controlo de idiomas é um problema a ter sempre em conta.

**Obter o idioma do browser.**
è uma prática a adoptar. Desta forma estamos já a seguir definições que o próprio browser com mecanismos próprios assegura e que nos entrega de bandeja.

No entanto isso pode não ser suficiente para alguns projectos sendo que e novamente por experiência é desejado uma alteração de idioma funcional durante a utilização do mesmo, ou porque alguém tranca o acesso às definições de um browser por exemplo. Mas por norma obter inicilamente o idioma a partir do browser é claramente o caminho a tomar.

A partir desse ponto, penso que a manipulação de uma `URL amigável` para definir um idioma é uma solução simples, eficáz e muito direta num projecto PHP e não só.

acesso normal:

```
www.meuprojecto.com/[controlador]/[acção]/[parametros] 
obtem as configurações do browser
```

acesso que afeta o idoma:

```
www.meuprojeto.com/pt/[controlador]/[acção]/[parametros]
força o idioma a ser pt "por exemplo"
```

Com esta abordagem os links são espalhados pelo projecto e a qualquer momento pode alterar o idioma.

A metodologia para guardar o idioma seleccionado depende da sua solução mas a gravação em COOKIE pode ser uma delas.