# Como pegar o idioma do usuário do navegador?

Tags: php, laravel, ip, geolocalização

Tenho um site em 3 idiomas, **PT-BR**, **EN** e **ES**.

Mas em algumas máquinas distintas quando acesso o site pelo navegador está direcionando para página em **Inglês**. Isso acontece por causa do código abaixo que desenvolvi para recuperar a linguagem do usuário do browser.

```
App::before(function($request){
    $l = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    $l = ($l == 'pt') ? null : $l;
    if(!is_null($l)){
        $l = in_array($l, Config::get('app.languages')) ? $l : 'en';
    }
});
```

Acontece que, obviamente, essa não é a melhor maneira. Alguns usuários por não saberem instalar um navegador, como o Chrome por exemplo, acabam o instalando em inglês. Daí o código redireciona o usuário para o site em inglês.

E isso está interferindo no Analytics do site. Pelo gráfico vejo que os usuários brasileiros estão acessando primeiro o site em Inglês e uma porcentagem destes clicam para entrar no em Português. O problema é que outros por verem que está em Inglês rejeitam o site, sem ao menos procurar a opção da troca de idioma.

Enfim, existe alguma maneira em PHP, Laravel para buscar o idioma do usuário de uma maneira mais global ?

Tipo por IP ?

Geolocalização ?

GeoIP ?

Comment: Sim, geralmente são APIs pagas... Está disposto a investir?

Comment: Manda aí. Qualquer coisa eu financio.

Comment: Já utilizei o projeto [laravel-geoip](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip), me atendeu perfeitamente.

Comment: Essa parece bacana @LúcioRubens, posta como resposta.

Comment: Estou tentando instalar esse do Rubens, porém, para a versão 4 do Laravel. Está dando um erro de pacote: `The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Operation timed out
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date`. Daí quando vou publicar dá pau.

Comment: É, tentei vários modos aqui e não deu certo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Tradução de [Resposta para *How to get the page visitors Country with PHP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12965822/3497987)

---

Você pode usar uma API externa como a [geoplugin.net](http://www.geoplugin.com/)

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=76.109.14.196");
echo $xml->geoplugin_countryName ;
```

Saída do País:

```
United States
```

Resposta XML completa:

```
<geoPlugin>
    <geoplugin_request>76.109.14.196</geoplugin_request>
    <geoplugin_status>200</geoplugin_status>
    <geoplugin_city>West Palm Beach</geoplugin_city>
    <geoplugin_region>FL</geoplugin_region>
    <geoplugin_areaCode>561</geoplugin_areaCode>
    <geoplugin_dmaCode>548</geoplugin_dmaCode>
    <geoplugin_countryCode>US</geoplugin_countryCode>
    <geoplugin_countryName>United States</geoplugin_countryName>
    <geoplugin_continentCode>NA</geoplugin_continentCode>
    <geoplugin_latitude>26.761600494385</geoplugin_latitude>
    <geoplugin_longitude>-80.091598510742</geoplugin_longitude>
    <geoplugin_regionCode>FL</geoplugin_regionCode>
    <geoplugin_regionName>Florida</geoplugin_regionName>
    <geoplugin_currencyCode>USD</geoplugin_currencyCode>
    <geoplugin_currencySymbol>&#36;</geoplugin_currencySymbol>
    <geoplugin_currencyConverter>1</geoplugin_currencyConverter>
</geoPlugin>
```

Simples função para pegar o IP:

```
function getIP() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) 
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

---

Algumas considerações que você tem que levar é que como seria uma requisição a uma API externa, o tempo de latência pode ser relativamente grande.

Ainda possui outras soluções como a [extensão GeoIP do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.geoip.php).

Comment: É arriscado usar essa API no caso desse site sair do ar um dia ?

Comment: @DiegoSouza arriscado sempre é, mas aquela resposta do site em inglês é de 2012 e testei antes de publicar a resposta e estava funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Entendi. Bom, vou utilizar. Se eu ver que está demorando muito a requisição darei outro eito. Tentei baixar alguma biblioteca para o Laravel, 4 mas nenhuma deu certo. Gostei da **laravel-geoip**, mas não deu certo de instalar.

Comment: A hospedagem do site está com a opção `allow_url_fopen` desabilitada.

Comment: A sua hospedagem @DiegoSouza? Tente com `cURL`... Ou entre em contato com o suporte e peça para que habilitem.

Comment: Já fiz isso. Deu certo!

Answer (score 5):

Para mim a sua questão não faz muito sentido da forma como a coloca. Percebo o problema que tem em mãos mas já pensou que hoje a internet é mobilidade?

O que acontece se o seu utilizador estiver noutro país... como pretende responder a isso por geolocalização? por ip?

Não me parece!

Para mim a forma certa para obter o idioma é sempre pelo navegador. exemplo:

```
/**
 * locale <i>Tag</i> do browser
 * @return string
 */
 private function _parse_client_language() {

        $http_accept = getenv('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');

        if (isset($http_accept) && strlen($http_accept) > 1) {
            # Split 
            $x = explode(",", $http_accept);
            foreach ($x as $val) {
                if (preg_match("/(.*);q=([0-1]{0,1}.d{0,4})/i", $val, $matches))
                    $lang[$matches[1]] = (float) $matches[2];
                else
                    $lang[$val] = 1.0;
            }

            #default language (highest q-value)
            $qval = 0.0;
            foreach ($lang as $key => $value) {
                if ($value > $qval) {
                    $qval = (float) $value;
                    return $key;
                }
            }
        }
        return self::$tag_default;
    }
```

Sigo muito a norma `LOCALE` que permite-nos, de forma standerizada, ter uma solução fácil e provada.

Depois recomendo a leitura da minha pergunta aqui no SO em:

[MVC e alteração dinâmica de idioma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66557/mvc-e-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-din%C3%A2mica-de-idioma)

Que até ao momento não obtive qualquer resposta mas dá uma ideia do problema que enfrentamos em qualquer projeto. Seja com `LARAVEL` ou  outro framework.

Comment: O público alvo não são turistas ou imigrantes. Obrigado.

Comment: @DiegoSouza mesmo assim. se browser é o cliente por excelência então este entrega o idioma de visualização. Tente disponibilizar ao utilizador uma forma de modificar o idioma e se ele o fizer atualize as suas estatísticas.

Comment: Não pode ser pelo browser. A ideia é a seguinte, se não for no Brasil acessa o site em inglês - idioma internacional. Então a GeoLocation me ajudaria nisso.

Comment: Testei seu código aqui. Meu Chrome é em **PT-BR**, mas retornou em **EN**. Está vendo a zica ?

Comment: Testei no Safari e no Firefox, retornou **PT-BR**.

Comment: em teste utilizo qualquer um dos browsers e funciona em todos. Tem de ter em conta no chrome qual o que tem de preferência. Quanto à sua opção de ir pelo geolocation... penso que nada mais lhe posso acrescentar.

Comment: Na minha opinião o mais correto é seguir o informado pelo browser; se a pessoa instalou o navegador em outra língua não vai ser só o seu site que vai ficar assim, até os menus do navegador ficam na outra língua não?