# Redirecionamento para subdomínio baseado no idioma do navegador

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Qual o método correto para direcionar a navegação de um site para uma página específica baseada no idioma do navegador do usuário?

Tenho um site (www.site.com) com o idioma padrão em inglês e preciso que, ao ser acessado em um navegador com o idioma Português (pt-br), ele redirecione a navegação para o subdomínio que criei e já hospedei os arquivos traduzidos (br.site.com).

O mesmo para espanhol (es.site.com) e italiano (it.site.com).

O que devo fazer? Que tipo de código devo inserir?

PS: **Já tenho as páginas traduzidas e hospedadas nos respectivos subdomínios**. Só preciso saber como identificar o idioma do navegador e direcionar automaticamente.

Como é feito isso no código? Javascript? PHP? Ajax? Via htacess? 
Alguém tem essa linha de código pra compartilhar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The book is on the table.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81073/como-pegar-o-idioma-do-usu%C3%A1rio-do-navegador

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte (colocar isto somente no site em inglês, que é o default, para não entrar em loop infinito):

```js
const sites = {
  'pt-br': 'http://br.site.com',
  'it': 'http://it.site.com',
  'es': 'http://es.site.com'
};

var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
lang = lang.toLowerCase(); // é possível a lang do navegador ser por ex: pt-BR
if(typeof sites[lang] !== 'undefined') {
  // window.location.replace(sites[lang]);
  alert('redirecionar para ' +sites[lang]);
}
```

[Códigos das linguagens do browser](http://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes)

Comentei o redirecionamento, mas será isso que deves usar.

Transformo a linguagem do retornada do browser para minuscula pois é muito possível que seja por ex: `pt-BR`, `en-US`, e temos de ter em concordância com as chaves do nosso objeto `sites`

Comment: Olá, Miguel! Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição. Era assim mesmo que eu esperava a resposta. Exatamente: O default será o inglês. Onde insiro esse código?

Comment: @Will , queres redirecionar a partir de todos? Se puseres este código em todos vais entrar num loop infinito. Vou editar para evitar isto

Comment: Será melhor, Miguel! Mas onde insiro esse código no código de exemplo da pergunta? No head? Crio uma tag <php> e colo esse codigo dentro? Sou iniciante. Só trabalho com html, css e jquery até o momento. Não conheço nada de PHP

Comment: @Will coloca este código somente no site em inglês, sim pode ser na head. assim: `<script>CODIGO POSTADO EM CIMA</script>`

Comment: Perfeito, Miguel! Vou fazer isso e já te dou um feedback!

Comment: Subi o html em português para br.nutryfruty.com e inseri o codigo acima no head de www.nutryfruty.com, como pode ser visto em F12. Mas não direcionou. Fiz algo errado?

Comment: Está exatamente como está em cima? Fiz uma edição que pode ser a chave @Will se fizeres `alert(lang);` antes do `if` o que dá?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54696/discussion-between-will-and-miguel).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar javascript para isso, segue exemplo abaixo:

```js
var lang = navigator.language;
alert(lang);
```

Comment: Olá, Matheus! Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição!

Neste caso, eu iria inserir esse codigo do head da pagina padrão? (www.site.com), tipo assim:

<script> var lang = navigator.language;
alert(lang);</script>